# Backbone.js set up

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm confused, cause I've been trying to find out how to set up a `Backbone.js` Project.
[This](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/a-complete-guide-for-learning-backbone-js/) is what I've got, I just need to include the scripts and then what? This is where I got lost, I'm pretty sure that simply opening the file I created wouldn't run the project, would it? And also I am following the video tutorial by **Thomas Davis** but the tutorial doesn't cover how to set up `Backbone.js` or how to run the project. I notice the difference in our `url`. What am I missing out? Also If you have some good material for starters like me. tnx!

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    <div id="page">
    </div>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var View = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function (){
                this.$el.html('Hello World');
            }
        });


        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '' : 'home'
            }
        });

        var view = new View();
        var router = new Router();
        router.on('route:home', function ()
        {
            view.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did You understand why @Devo called `backboneJS` in the end?
Because, `backbone` use `jquery`, `underscore` and template(here template is `jquery-ui`)

Comment: Yes I understand at least that much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting Backbone

You should include the `undescore.js`, `jquery.js` and `backbone.js` in your html and then simply run the file just like normal web app.

If you are familiar with apache, put your app in web root and access like `http://localhost/my_app/`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Download `underscorejs` from [here](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js) and put in `js` folder.

Download `jquery` [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js).

Download `Backbone` [here](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js).

And then place your backbone function in external JavaScript file and include it after backbone.js.

### Fix

And there is something error with your code. You are defined your element using `id` but trying to access using class notation.

So replace,

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function (){
             this.$el.html('Hello World');
        }
});
```

with,

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#page',
        render: function (){
             this.$el.html('Hello World');
        }
});
```

You have to use `el: '#page'`.

You should include dependencies before including backbone.js.

So replace,

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

With,

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Underscore.js`, `jquery.js` and `backbone.js`.. I've already included these.. then I just open it like a normal web page like this `file:///C:/Backbone_js/SampleProject1/index.html` ?

Comment: So that was really it huh.. cause the tutorial I've been looking at had this kind of url `localhost\..\..\..\` and says 'tutorial for beginners',

Comment: If you are familiar with apache, the best practice is to place your project in web root and access like ``http://localhost/your_project/``.

Comment: That's it, haha, I'm pretty much familiar with web programming, it's the frameworks  that are new to me.. thanks

Comment: I got it running on the localhost and I copied the tutorial, but mine's not working just like in the tutorial

Comment: Done. I just added it to my post if that's ok.. At first the `router` and `view` is on a separate `js` file and I just call them using `<script>` but it's not working so I tried doing it according to the tutorial, still no output though